# How to forward user's text to another dialog

Tags: botframework, bots

I offer the user some options in a menu, when they choose an option I replace the current dialog for them to start the valid dialog for the selected option, but if the user types something that its not in the menu I want to use AI to send them the right option but when I use `stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync` the original text from the user is lost. How can I preserve the original text and forward it to the next dialog where the AI can process it?

Comment: Can you post your code, please? Also, it looks like this is for the C# SDK. Is that right?

Comment: user10860402 is correct. I misunderstood your question from the get go. You can reference this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#check-for-interruptions-each-turn) from the docs as well as the [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.replacedialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_DialogContext_ReplaceDialogAsync_System_String_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

Comment: @StevenKanberg yes, it is for c#. What exactly do you need of the code, just to know, because I think it is not needed

Comment: As I mentioned, I misunderstood your question. Thinking it more complex than it was, working with more information to help provide a solution is generally preferred. To that end, I would recommend you review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it along your replace dialog code

```
stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(YourDialog),yourText);
```

And access it on your new dialog by

```
var result = stepContext.Options as string;
```

Comment: Yes, as the schema link (in the above comments) indicates: `options Object` (Optional) additional argument(s) to pass to the new dialog